# a property which observers another property?

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0

I have a changing property.

```
@property Model selected;
```

After that, created another property to put in the markup, to toggle disabled based on a property of Model.

```
@property bool get isDeleted => selected.deleted;
```

but it seems that `isDeleted` doesnt change in the markup.

```
<my-element disabled$="{{isDeleted}}"></my-element>
```

I checked with both values so disabled works as intended but isDeleted doesnt update I am thinking.

That being said,  can i add an observer to isDeleted to observe selected, or would i need to create a function and do a computed property instead of shorthand

```
@Property(observer:"selected") bool get isDeleted => ! selected.deleted;
```

or should i do something akin to:

```
@Property(computed:"toggle(selected)") bool isDeleted;

@reflectable bool toggle(Model m) => !m.deleted;
```

I tried to do computed based on a property, but it needs a function, therefore, I cant use shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i endedup doing was:

```
@property Model selected;
@property bool isDeleted

@Observe("selected")
toggle(selected){
  set("isDeleted", !selected.deleted);
}
```